# Why is my file_text_read_string not working in GML?

Tags: gml

I have the below GML code where I am attempting to read strings from "mygame.txt". When I run the code, the array is just filled with "". I found the buffer section of code and I can see that the var s actually contains the contents of my game. Any idea why the array, arr[] does not properly read the string?

```
lines= 0
var file = file_text_open_read("mygame.txt"); // need to store in "data files" folder

if (file!= -1){
    while (!file_text_eof(file)) {
        file_text_readln(file);
        lines++;
    }
    var file_buffer = buffer_load("mygame.txt");
    var s = buffer_read(file_buffer, buffer_string);
    buffer_delete(file_buffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < lines; ++i;){
        arr[i] = file_text_read_string(file);
        file_text_readln(file);
    }
    file_text_close(file);

    for (var i = 0; i < 1; ++i;){

    }}
```

Comment: If you're using `++i` in a for loop, I think it'll skip the first iteration of the loop. So it's a better practice to use `i++`, or at least in for loops.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I will take a look at that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array arr[] is displaying blanks because in

```
while (!file_text_eof(file)) {
        file_text_readln(file);
        lines++;
    }
```

I was reading the file through to the end of the file in order to mistakenly get the # of lines in the file for the for loop.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < lines; ++i;){
        arr[i] = file_text_read_string(file);
        file_text_readln(file);
    }
```

At this point, I am already at the end of the file and therefore no more lines exist. The above for loop processed regardless because the it doesn't care that I was already at the end of file. So all of the indexes in arr[] are blank because it's trying to read lines that don't exist.

To resolve, after the while loop I closed and reopened the file before the for loop.

lines= 0
var file = file_text_open_read("mygame.txt"); // need to store in "data files" folder

```
if (file!= -1){
    while (!file_text_eof(file)) {
        file_text_readln(file);
        lines++;
    }
    file_text_close(file);
    file_text_open_read(file);
    for (var i = 0; i < lines; ++i;){
        arr[i] = file_text_read_string(file);
        file_text_readln(file);
    }
    file_text_close(file);

    for (var i = 0; i < 1; ++i;){

    }}
```

Another code example by YellowAfterlife is the proper coding

```
    lines = 0;
    var file = file_text_open_read("mygame.txt");
    if (file != -1) {
        while (!file_text_eof(file)) {
            arr[lines] = file_text_read_string(file);
            file_text_readln(file);
            lines++;
            }
        file_text_close(file);
        // arr is now populated with lines from the file
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are:

- Reading the file line by line without saving the strings anywhere
- Reading the entirety of a file to a string that you never use
- Doing an actual loop to read lines of text from a file, except `lines` is still 0 so it executes 0 times
  (and also you've already read that file until end-of-file so this isn't going to work anyway)

Rest assured, that doesn't work - you have all the parts to do so but they are mashed up with non-functioning code. Could have been

```
lines = 0;
var file = file_text_open_read("mygame.txt");
if (file != -1) {
    while (!file_text_eof(file)) {
        arr[lines] = file_text_read_string(file);
        file_text_readln(file);
        lines++;
    }
    file_text_close(file);
    // arr is now populated with lines from the file
}
```

Comment: Thanks @YellowAfterlife. I disagree with your bullet points on what the issue is. However the code you mention looks correct (I haven't tested it out yet.) The main issue I found (and noobishly forgot to add as solved here) is that I read through the entire file to get the "lines" count. Then I went in and tried to continue reading the file- even though I was already at the end of the file. The solution is as you mentioned, read to eof. Instead of rewriting all of my code, I just closed the file and reinitialized it so that it would read properly to the "lines" integer and it took off. Thanks!